# Which airlines allow in-cabin pets on transatlantic flights?

Tags: air-travel, pets

I would like to bring my small (9 lbs) dog on a flight from the U.S. to Germany as "carry on" (in-cabin).

Apparently neither Continental airlines nor American airlines allows in-cabin pets on flights from the U.S. to Europe.

Which airlines do allow in-cabin pets on flights from the U.S. to Europe?

[cross-posted: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/travel-pets/1270995-transatlantic-cabin-pet.html ]

Comment: wow, that's an interesting question! Would never even have considered it possible.

Comment: Lufthansa *does* allow animals on transatlantic flights.

Comment: U.S. Airways does **not** allow animals on transatlantic flights.

Comment: I suggest putting your comments into an answer, as they're quite useful and relevant, and do answer the question.

Comment: Interesting question, now I also know which airline to ignore. Imagine to be seated cramped next to a dog that freaks out because of the sound, dehydration, turbulence. . Uncontrolled children is one thing, but uncontrolled animals, are in my perspective, even worse.

Comment: United Airlines no longer accepts pets in cabin for flights to Europe.

Comment: Probably another casualty of the Continental merger. )-:

Comment: It is amazing that this is possible, and indeed relatively common. I only learned recently it was possible, and was amazed to learn this. It's funny, I've never, ever heard an animal (cat or small dog) during a flight!! You'd think it would be fairly common to hear them.

Comment: Here is a nice table of various airline policies for international pet travel, last updated in 2013: http://www.dogjaunt.com/guides/international-airline-pet-policies-for-in-cabin-travel/  United will allow in-cabin pets on some flights but the acceptance "varies widely" so the best bet is to call them. Other airlines have clearer policies.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I spent about half the day yesterday booking my flights.   Here is the info I found:

- *Airlines that do **not** allow in-cabin pets on transatlantic flights:* **American, Continental, U.S. Airways**
- *Airlines that **do** allow in-cabin pets on transatlantic flights:* **Delta, Lufthansa, United**

These are personally verified by calling the airlines, and by taking my dog to Germany from Frankfurt on Lufthansa.

Comment: kudos for coming band and updating your answer!

Comment: Now that United and Continental have merged, what is their policy on this?

Comment: Turkish airlines allows in cabin pets, I have had wonderful experiences traveling with a small dog from U.S. to Europe and back.

Comment: For 2015, XL Airways does allow cats in-cabin (and also in-hold).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like United will, but you would have to double-check as they mention on another page that certain planes and routes cannot accept pets in-cabin.

[United fees for pets](http://www.united.com/page/article/1,,53410,00.html)

[General United information on pets](http://www.united.com/page/middlepage/0,6998,1047,00.html)

Comment: I called United Reservations to check and it seems that they *do* accept trans-atlantic in-cabin pets.

Answer (score 6):

United will only accept Transatlantic pets onboard in the Cargo Hold.  United will allow small domestic cats/dogs in cabin but you must be in Economy and seated by a window.  No in cabin pets allowed in Business/1st Class, due to inadequate seat configurations for under seat storage[747/757/767/777].

Air France does accept in-cabin pets for crossing the pond with prior approval from the Telephone sales service. Dogs/cats weighing less than 6kg/13.2lbs (including transport bag or container).

Lufthansa also allows in cabin pets[Dogs/Cats/Ferrets] for 8kg/17.6lbs total for animal & carrier combined.

I do not know about the seating for AF and if there is only a specific class that you may bring your pet into, but Lufthansa allows your pet to accompany you in Any Class! Just make sure you call them first before you click on your fare online, and they will tell you if there is availability on your chosen flight[s] for your pet in cabin.

Comment: References to the documentation of these would be nice.